# How to pause after output in assembly using nasm

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I have a problem when i trying to learn assembler, i copied som code from a book
and after i installed nasm for 64bit processor and GoLink.

After some tries a was able to compile it to an exe file that should display "Hello world" in the comand promt.

The program "works" but i cant see "hello world" i guess its becouse it never stops, or the fact that the book i read is assembly for linux - but both use x86 if im not wrong.

This is the code:

```
section .data
    msg db      "Hello, World",0
section .bss
section .text
    global START
START:
        mov rax, 1
        mov rdi,1
        mov rsi, msg
        mov rdx, 12
        syscall
        mov rax, 60
        mov rdi ,0
syscall
```

I dont want to link to c i want to code raw assembly.

Comment: Yeah, this code is for Linux; the syscalls are following the Linux API.  It's fundamentally not going to work on Windows.  You can either install Linux if you want to write code for it, or if you want to write code for Windows, get a different book.

Comment: They are both x86, so the same instructions execute on both; that much is true.  But the question is *which* instructions you need to execute in order to get the OS to perform a particular action like outputting a string, and that differs greatly between OSes.  It is like saying "English and French both use sound waves, so I should be able to walk into a shop in Houston and say 'Je prendrai un café, s'il vous plaît' and receive a coffee."

Comment: Your question title seems unrelated to what you describe in the question.  Running this from an already-open shell window will leave the output on the screen, if there is any.  Or  redirect the output to a file or pipe into hexdump.  Wanting to pause after output is normally a Windows problem because people often configure their stuff to run a program in a window that closes as soon as the program exits.  That's just silly; don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

When I need to make a program pause i will add “pause:jmp short pause” before the end of the code segment.this is a silly method,but it works.

Comment: If you're going to busy-wait instead of making a system call, at least put a [`pause`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pause) instruction in the loop to waste somewhat less power.